# On ENTER keyup - Execute Function inside form and not submit the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, datatables

I have a table with filterable data using the jQuery DataTables library.
This table is inside a form that, when rows are CHECKED (in one column there is a checkbox), the SUBMIT button will add them to a collection.

Attached to the table is a custom search filter that functions like the built-in search filter that comes with DataTables, but instead of a "filter as you type" functionality, I have a submit button attached so that it will not filter the table results until you click the button.  There is some functionality added to that search filter that actually runs an ajax call to a database, and to reduce the amount of calls to the database, I put the button on the search filter and disabled the "filter as you type" functionality.

I STILL want to be able to click the ENTER key on my keyboard when I have finished typing in my search filter to execute this custom search, but I am unable to stop the form from submitting.  I have the custom search filter in a function called `"tableFilter()"`. The ID of the form is `"#addtitle"`

```
$("#addTitle").on('keyup', function(e){
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        console.log('keyup');
        if (keyCode == 13){
            console.log('ENTER PRESSED');
            if ($("#dataTables_filter_input").is(":focus")){
                console.log('FILTER FOCUS');
                tableFilter();
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

I figured that if the input field of the search was still in focus, that would be enough of a difference for the code to know that when I click ENTER, it would execute the search filter and not submit the form - yet the form still submits.

Do I have things out of order? Am I not calling the right functions?

Comment: Make the button a `type="button"` to not have it submit the form

Comment: Change type="submit" or `$("#addTitle").on('keyup', function(e){` to `$("#formID").on('submit', function(e){ e.preventDefault();`

Comment: can you give your datatables script too?

Answer (score 1):

we must know the mechanical first.

```
<form>
<input type="text">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

if you pressed ENTER in input text. it will trigger:

1. button submit clicked
2. form submitted
3. input text keyup [ENTER]

if you want prevent default behaviour. You must use preventDefault() on `$('form').submit` [only], in other word you dont  need type preventDefault() in `$('input[type="submit"]').click` or `$('input[type="text"]').keyup`

so, your jquery will like this

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
})

$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(e){
var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (keyCode == 13){
            //do something
        }
})
```

but you will never can use submit button to trigger form input. To do form submit you must use type="button" to trigger form submit.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/pirepahuhu/edit?html,output

===============

this what i think to force solved this problem

demo: http://jsbin.com/hiqatetoti/2/edit?html,output

```
<form>
    another text input<input type="text"><br>
    add title<input type="text" id="addTitle"><br>
    another text input<input type="text"><br>
    <input type="button" value="button"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"><br>
  </form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<Script>
  $(function(){
  $("#addTitle").on('keyup', function(e){
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (keyCode == 13){
            console.log("ENTER PRESSED on input text");
        }
    });

  $('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).find('#addTitle').is(':focus') === false){
      doAjaxForm();
    }
  });

  function doAjaxForm(){
    console.log('do ajax form');
  }  

})
  </script>
```

- if form submitted but #addTitle has focused = do nothing, then addTtitle keyup will do your job
- if form submitted but #addTitle not focussed = do ajax form
- if you press enter on another text input (except #addTitle) , this will trigger form submit = do ajax form
- if submit button clicked = do ajax form

i hope this will work for you, since you dont give us your datatables script.

Comment: the issue isn't with the dataTables at all. In fact the same occurrence would happen if a standard HTML table was in a form.So I wonder why you would need the dataTables script?

Comment: i cant speak english well to explain that. but try to see this http://jsbin.com/nuhiqijuqa/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

```
let cancelEvent = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
};

let filter = document.getElementById('dataTables_filter_input');
let addTitle = document.getElementById('addTitle');
let form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', cancelEvent);

addTitle.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  let keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

  console.log('KEYUP');

  if (keyCode !== 13 || !filter.is(':focus')) {
    console.log('NOT ENTER PRESSED OR FILTER NOT FOCUS');
    return true;
  }

  tableFilter();
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: clicking ENTER with the field in focus DOES return the filter results, but still submits the form almost immediately after the results are displayed.